# Integral trace sequences

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, integers

Let $A$ and $B$ be commuting complex square matrices.

Assume that $Tr(A^n)$ is an integer for each $n \ge 0$.

If the characteristic polynomial of $B$ has integer coefficients, does it necessarily follow that $Tr(BA^n)$ are all integers as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider e.g. $A=\operatorname{diag}(\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2})$ and $B=\operatorname{diag}(1,0)$.